# Using Instruments 'Allocation' with an iPad App

Tags: cocoa, ipad, memory, instruments

I've got an issue with my iPad app. After running for approx. 15 minutes, it crashes with "Program received signal:  “0". showing in the log file. From Google, I've discovered this is probably a memory useage problem. In the Console log on the iPad there's also a couple of memory warnings before the crash which seem to confirm this.

I've run my app in Instruments (xcode 'Run' -> 'Run with Performance Tool' -> 'Allocations'). This is where I start to get a bit confused. Instruments shows me 'Live Bytes' and 'Overall Bytes'. As I understand it, 'Live Bytes' is the actual memory 'footprint' of the app, and 'Overall Bytes' is the total count of all the memory that's been allocated and subsequently released. In my app, 'Live Bytes' sits at approx. 1.5 MB, while 'Overall Bytes' gradually rises to 500 MB at which point the app crashes.

My question is how much memory is my app **actually** using? 500 MB certainly seems like a problem for an iPad, but 1.5 MB certainly doesn't.

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: Does this also happen if you do not use the app for 15 minutes? Just let it run and do nothing? Also, try enabling NSZombie.

Comment: The app just (at the moment) displays data received from an external accessory, so the only mode the app has is 'just let it run'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an actual reading of how much memory your application is using, don't use the Object Allocations instrument, but instead turn to the Memory Monitor one.  The latter will give the actual in-memory size of your total application.

Where Object Allocations is great is for determining which objects you are accumulating using the new heapshot functionality.  I highly recommend reading Bill Bumgarner's [article on the subject](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

Comment: Great, thanks! Think that's pointed me in the right direction.